# Direct computation of $\pi_n(S^n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Could anyone help me to prove 
 $$\pi_n(S^n) \quad  \text{is homomorphic to}\quad \mathbb{Z}.$$

There is so many solutions in books with the help of homp theory.
But I want to prove it directly without help of any other theory. I think maybe I could prove it by induction. Is it ok ?
I have found a proof form the book Homology Theory. But I’m not sure about it. It says :

Example. Let $<\alpha>$ be a class in $\pi_1(S^1,x_0)$, where $x_0$ is chosen to be the point $(1,0)$ in $S^l$. Using the covering space $exp: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$, we lift $\alpha$ to a path in $\mathbb{R}$ with initial point $0$. The terminal point of this lift is an integer which we denote $d(\alpha)$. Since any loop homotopic to $\alpha$ must lift to a path with the same terminal point, $d(\alpha)$ depends only on the class of $\alpha$ in $\pi_1(S^1,x_0)$.Consequently, $d$ defines a function from $\pi_1(S^1,x_0)$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Note that if the initial point of the lift of $\alpha$ is taken to be the integer $k$, then the terminal point of the lift will be $k + d(\alpha)$. Consequently, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are loops at $x_0$, then $d(\alpha \cdot \beta) = d(\alpha) + d(\beta)$. In other words, we have produced a homomorphism 
$$d:\pi_1(S^1,x_0) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}, $$
called the *degree* of the loop.

For any integer $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ there is a path $\widetilde{\gamma}$ from $0$ to $m$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Projecting this path down to the base, $\gamma = exp\widetilde{\gamma}$ is a loop at $x_0$ for which $d(\gamma) = m$; hence $d$ is an epimorphism. On the other hand, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be loops in $S^1$ with $d(\alpha) = k = d(\beta)$. So the lifts $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{\beta}$ are paths in $\mathbb{R}$ with initial point $0$ and terminal point $k$. Define a function 
$$H: [0,1] \times [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
by $H(t,s) = (1-s)\widetilde{\alpha}(t) + s\widetilde{\beta}(t), 0 \geq s \geq 1$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is convex, this is well defined and continuous. 
This homotopy from $\widetilde{\alpha}(s = 0)$ to $\widetilde{\beta}(s = 1)$ fixes the endpoints at $0$ and $k$ throughout the deformation. Then $exp H$ is a based homotopy from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. Therefore $<\alpha>=<\beta>$, and $d$ is a monomorphism. This completes the proof of the following proposition.

4.6 Proposition. The degree of a loop defines an isomorphism 
$$d:\pi_1(S^1,x_0) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}.$$

> Specifically I look for the special case of $n=1, 2, 3, 4,... $

Comment: Prove it first for $n=1$. (Hint: $S^1$ has a nice covering space)

Comment: I think this is not so easy to prove. There is a sophisticated theory behind this for a reason.

Comment: The most "elementary" proof I know of this is essentially the Hopf degree theorem that maps $S^n \to S^n$ up to homotopy are classified by their degree. This invariant is either defined using homology (the induced map on $H_n(S^n) \cong \Bbb Z$) or via smooth approximation and a smooth definition of degree (which doesn't require homology). Ultimately, however, this is a nontrivial and interesting theorem which requires some work to prove. It's very unclear to me in what sense you want to use the homotopy lifting lemma.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes, I think Hopf was the first person prove this, and his paper is not that easy to read, but Whitney gave a simplified proof which is quite nice, though non trivial.

Comment: Wikipedia gives  Brouwer, L. E. J. (1911). "Über Abbildung von Mannigfaltigkeiten". Mathematische Annalen. 71 (1): 97–115, and the theorem for mappings of $S^n$ is usually known as the "Brouwer degree theorem". It is proved n the book "Nonabelian AlgebraicTopology" (EMS,  2011), without using covering spaces or singular homology theory; but setting up the required  higher dimension  Seifert-van Kampen Theorem is not easy,

Comment: Sometimes hard theorems are hard.

Comment: Why not just use the theory that was developed to solve exactly this kind of problem?

Comment: I don't think there is a "direct" way. In fact, this question lead to the development of many tools in algebraic topology; so I guess at some point you need to actually use those. (If you haven't already,take a look at  the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres.

Comment: Please, replace "homeomorphic" with "isomorphic" and correct the title to something like "Direct computation of $\pi_n(S^n)$".

Comment: @MoisheCohen thanks for you attention , I changed it to computation , but I nedd exactly to show this homomorphism for n=1,2,3,4

Comment: @RonnieBrown so what about writing it for n=1,2,3 .. to see what’ll happened ?

Comment: Your question is still meaningless as written: What does "homomorphic to" mean? Admits a nontrivial homomorphism? Admits an epimorphism? Is isomorphic to?

Comment: @Tyrone I write it for $n=1$ and $n=2$ could you please give me a hint for $n=3$ and $n=4$ I think for 3 and 4 it is so difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure its easy to do without *any* other homotopy theory. One way is to use the Freudenthal Suspension theorem starting with what you have for $n=1$. There is also the Hopf map $\eta:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ which is a a fibration with fibre $S^1$, which might help you with $n=2,3$. You can also use some CW theory to show that $\pi_iS^n=0$ for $0<i<n$ which will be useful for some calculations.

Comment: The simplest proof that $\pi_n(S^n)=Z$ for $n\ge 2$ is via Hurewicz isomorphism. First you argue that $\pi_k(S^n)=0$ for $0<k< n$. There are several arguments for this, this simplest uses simplicial approximation. Then comes the hard part. Hurewicz gives you an isomorphism $\pi_n(S^n)=H_n(S^n)$. Then you use Mayer-Vietoris sequence to conclude that $H_n(S^n)=Z$. All this is covered in any algebraic topology textbook. Any alternative proof will be much more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a proof in the book [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html) p.269. It derives from a Suspension Theorem which says that if the space $A$ is $(n-2)$-connected for $n\geqslant 3$ then its suspension $SA$ is $(n-1)$-connected and $\pi_n(SA) \cong \pi_{n-1}(A)$. However this itself is deduced from a higher order Seifert-van Kampen Theorem, whose main applications are given in Chapter 8 of the book, and whose proof is not easy; so I do not really expect that   this approach meets the (rather hard) criteria! The proof though does not use singular homology.

Comment: Dear Ronnie: The link is broken, could you fix it?

Comment: @Moishe Cohen Thanks! Fixed.